# How to add a Static message ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I need to add a little blip about an update to a form and I'm making it unnecessarily hard on myself. How do I add a text field that simply says `Notice: XYZ` underneath the Transfer date field? Is it a certain xtype I need to implement?

[image]

Comment: Which ext version are you using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible way to add textfield/ displayfield in your form. Get hold of form and then add the textfield. Or simply add the textfield in form panel. 
I created a fiddler for you in that I am adding next to 'Transfer Date' by this way.

```
{
    xtype :'textfield',    
    name: 'last',
    editable :false,
    allowBlank: false,
    fieldLabel: 'Notice',
    value: 'xyz'
}
```

Since you asked for `textfield` so we can do like that and make `editable :false,` but the easier option is to achieve this is

```
   {
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Notice',
    value: 'xyz'   
   }
```

Both type of solution is available in fiddler. Have a look and choose as per your choice. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1eec)

Answer (score 1):

Add in your form object

```
formPanel.add({
    xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Notice',
        value: 'xyz'    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a new component of xtype: label to your form panel.

for example:

```
formPanel.add({
    xtype: 'label',
    text: 'Notice: XYZ'
});
```